# Cordova not allowing call to untrusted https server for WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch, ssl-certificate

I have developed an application with Sencha Touch and packaged it using Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7 for WP8.

My application make service calls to a server that has an untrusted SSL installed(by untrusted SSL I mean that SSL certificate which is not issued by registered Certifying Authority). But Cordova is not allowing the application to hit such URL's. The service calls returns a "0" status code with no status text.

I've also raised a JIRA issue regarding the same [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8492), but there has been no response yet.

Can somebody help find a way to bypass SSL error in Cordova code for WP8.

Comment: I think whitelisting that url will solve your problem.

Comment: @SujataChanda I had whitelisted all url's i.e., I wrote access origin=* in the config file, but the problem was at server with incorrect installation of ssl certificate. Now its solved after fixing installation of ssl at server.

Comment: Now, I would like to see an answer that works without working SSL certificates. I only found [a solution for android and ios](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-certificate-plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lied at server with installation of ssl certificate. The application is able to hit url's without making any change in cordova or app code, but just by correctly installing ssl certificate on server.